# Edit out external broken links to refiddle (displaying spam)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, clean-up, broken-link

I noticed that refiddle.com, a site likely used to test regular expressions, is no longer active and links to a spam site. An [issue was raised](https://github.com/phallguy/refiddle-com/issues/20) on the official repo in 2021, but it appears that the project has been abandoned and we can no longer rely on it to stay up.

We need some help to:

1. edit out the broken links from the questions/answers, or
2. if by removing the link, the answer does not make sense, flag as "not an answer" or vote to delete

Please do not flag these posts as spam.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3A%22refiddle.com%22 (217 results)

Thanks

Comment: There is an unsecured refiddle.co.

Comment: If the editors have enough time they may replace the link with one pointing to https://regex101.com or https://regexr.com. **Iff** the demo link really is needed.

Comment: @Lino "*Iff the demo link really is needed.*" it shouldn't be. Because in that case, it's a link-only answer. But it's a nice to have for an actual answer.

Comment: @VLAZ yeah that's what I meant, if its just a complementary link to a good answer, it may be better to replace it than to just remove it.

Comment: If we find any comments with a link to refiddle, what would be the correct action? NLN for link only comments, and flag for edit if the comment contains enough information without it?

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship it seems it has all of the data from the old one as well. Just changing the domain in the link seems to fix it.

Comment: *If* that is the case, and ".com" should now be ".co" (and presumably https -> http) then it would seem a better™ option for maybe someone at [so] to have [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) rewrite the URLs. That could also (hopefully) address the comments out there too.

Comment: @ThomA all of the ones I removed seemed to be "http" so maybe their wasn't a secure version of the site to start with.

Comment: I freely admit that I just *assume* that any *good* site would use https now-a-days, @AbdulAzizBarkat , considering how accessible its implementation is.

Comment: Not all refiddle.com links are also valid refiddle.co links, so replacing them automatically with the community bot probably isn't acceptable. Especially the short form links seems to often just not work.

Comment: Well at least a updated link that works some/most of the time is better than one that directly links to a spam domain...

Comment: @Cerbrus Creating broken links is unhelpful. When editing and the link is invalid either delete the link, replace it with a regex101 link, or flag as low quality. Note that more than half of the posts have been fixed already

Comment: I was under the impression we were talking about some automated replacement, @mousetail. Sure, manual edits can do better :D

Comment: @Cerbrus Automated replacement is not viable because of the issues mentioned, and especially since the manual replacement is almost done

Comment: [32282](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/) (by far the highest scored at this time (78 remaining)) is [locked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I unlocked and fixed the answer, thanks

Comment: I just checked and saw only two remaining results in the search: I was able to edit one and flag the other NAA.